# removing a repo from a group in gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I've a gitolite setup, my gitolite.conf file looks like,

```
@myrepos = test
@myrepos = proj1 proj2

repo @myrepos
    RW+ = user1 user2 user3 user4
```

Now, I'd like to give access to a new user "user5" to "proj2" alone.
Is there a way to do it in gitolite without removing the repo from the group?

If I were to remove the repo "proj2" from the group to place it separately, would that break something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define another rule just for user5 and proj2, which means you don't have to modify `myrepos` group.

```
repo @myrepos
    RW+ = user1 user2 user3 user4

repo proj2
    RW+ = user5
```

Comment: It took some time to verify :)